# Action Execution Specification usage in Sequence Diagram

Tags: eclipse-plugin, uml, modeling, papyrus

As I read through `UML Reference Manual 2004`

there are some examples about `action` :

1)`creating and destroying object`

2)`calling an operation`

3)`sending signal to other object`

**My First question is :**

Does this mean that I should use `action Execution Specification` not  `Behaviour Execution Specification` when I want to  create those types of actions?
As you can see

[image]

**My Second question is :**

In which cases I should use `Behaviour Execution Specification` ??

PS: I use Papyrus for modelling the above example

Answer (score 1):

You actually read UML reference Manual 2004!? I guess it deals with UML1.5 (officially defined in March 2003) which should be different than UML2.x modeled thanks Papyrus...

Comment: What is the difference ?

Comment: Do you mean that the definition of action changed in UML2 than in UML 1.5?

Comment: because I didn't realize the difference until now

Comment: The question is not about action. It is about BehaviourExecutionSpecification and ActionExecutionSpecification which are part of UML 2.x and not UML1.5 ...

Comment: According to the UML 2.1.1 specification, BehaviourExecutionSpecification and ActionExecutionSpecification are both ExecutionSpecification but the first one is related to the execution of an Behaviour (which might be referenced) and the second one to the execution of an Action (which must be referenced).

Comment: thank you @Red Beard ,In which cases I should use Behaviour Execution Specification because I would like to understand the relation between  Behaviour/action Execution Specification and the message that may be considered operation call(synchronous), signal(asynchronous),creating/destroying object?

Comment: and what is the semantic of the action/behaviour which must be referenced in the case of Action/Behaviour Execution Specification?

Comment: You would use BehaviourExecutionSpecification when you want to reference a Behaviour and an ActionExecutionSpecification for referencing an Action... 
In which case do you have to use a Behaviour or an Action, it depends of your needs / what you want to express. If your referenced element needs to be refined or described in details, a Behaviour (Interaction, Activity or StateMachine) would be useful. If you do not need do not need to describe in details your referenced element I would use an Action.

Comment: thanks @RedBeard for your useful answers in UML tag.
could you please help me find an example about using 'ActionExecutionSpecification' and 'BehaviourExecutionSpecification' as you mentioned in the last comment .I really interested to know about them
I googled about them and also read in the spec but I didn't find something useful